# Android Kotlin future notification with worker with method from main activity

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, worker

I want to schedule my MainActivty to perform checks on its data periodically without showing UI to the user.  When a condition is true, I want to show a notification.
Furthermore, I need to check for this notification only once per day, without an exact timing and I want this check to remain scheduled even if the device is rebooted /after poweron.

Looks like the worker model with TimeUnit.ONE_DAY is the best fit for me (Here I am setting the interval at one minute so I don't need to wait for one day to test).

I create in "onCreate" method the Periodic Request Builder and the enqueue the request in the work manager.

Outside onCreate method I define the sendNotification method and provide my class implementatio on Notification Worker, where I define the action to be performed when the woker callback is fired.

In main class I have:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
      override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      [...]
      val CheckRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<NotificationWorker>(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build()
      WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(CheckRequest)
      }

fun sendNotification(){
    with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)) {
        notify(notificationId, builder.build())
    }

class NotificationWorker(appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters):
    Worker(appContext, workerParams) {
    override fun doWork(): Result {
        // Do the work here--in this case, upload the images.
        MainActivity().sendNotification()
        // Indicate whether the work finished successfully with the Result
        return Result.success()
      }
   }
}
```

My Issue is that I encounter the following error

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

I think that what's happening is that I am calling a method from the super class of the worker when the UI is not active, so the app context etc is not availlable to the called method.

Any hin on this point would be gladly appreciated.
Kind regards,

Comment: `MainActivity().sendNotification()` never ever instantiate an Activity by hand

Comment: Ok, I was pretty sure that this was worst practice but I needed it for a fast test. Any further indication?

Comment: Technically your actual issue is caused by how the coroutine of a Worker by default runs on a background thread, and sending the notification will only work in a `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)` block.

Comment: I think I understand your point, but still I can't picture the solution of my issue.

Comment: You are looking for https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker#setForegroundAsync(androidx.work.ForegroundInfo)